# Selecting words from a discord message not working

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

Pretty new to coding. Want to make a discord bot with python. I have this code. All seems ok but when the keyword is typed the bot just spams the response. What have I done wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5pxA.jpg

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    if 'donate' in message.content:
        await client.send_message(channel, 'To donate click this link http://www.test.com')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matching/selection of words work fine.

You only have a logic error: the bot will also listen for messages *sent by itself*. Since the message emitted by the bot also contains the word `donate` (between `To` and `click`), your bot will recursively reply to itself. To fix this, add these lines to the start of your `on_message` function:

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

This will filter out messages sent by the bot.

Comment: Ah thank you so much. That has fixed the problem instantly. I never even considered that the bot would be reading itself. Many thanks